# Using pygodaddy module to update IP address of my domain

Tags: python, dns

I saw [an example](https://saschpe.wordpress.com/2013/11/12/godaddy-dyndns-for-the-poor/) that use [pygodaddy](https://pygodaddy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to update IP address of my domain.
Here is the python script (removed account info):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import logging
import pif
import pygodaddy

LOG_PATH = '/Users/csj/godaddy.log'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_PATH, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
GODADDY_USERNAME="MY_LOGIN_ID"
GODADDY_PASSWORD="MYPASSWORD"
client = pygodaddy.GoDaddyClient()

try:
    client.login(GODADDY_USERNAME, GODADDY_PASSWORD)
    for domain in client.find_domains():
        dns_records = client.find_dns_records(domain)
        public_ip = pif.get_public_ip()
        logging.debug("Domain '{0}' DNS records: {1}".format(domain, dns_records))
        # only update if IP not the same with previous one
        if public_ip != dns_records[0].value:
            client.update_dns_record(domain, public_ip)
            logging.info("Domain '{0}' public IP set to '{1}'".format(domain, public_ip))
except Exception, err:
    logging.info("Error: %s" % err)
```

after execute the script, everything looks fine. The log is as below:

> 015-02-01 18:00:30,200 Starting new HTTPS connection (1):
>   dns.godaddy.com 2015-02-01 18:00:31,134 Starting new HTTPS connection
>   (1): idp.godaddy.com 2015-02-01 18:00:36,779 Starting new HTTP
>   connection (1): v4.ident.me 2015-02-01 18:00:38,654 Domain 'csj.io'
>   public IP set to '122.121.103.37'

However, I checked the manager panel in godaddy website, the IP address did not change. neither by ping it.

Is there any convenient to update IP address of my domain?
or anything I can try on the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an exploit on Godaddy that was patched on Jan 18, and that broke PyGodaddy. There´s a new version of the script on Github.

Comment: thanks a lot, after re-install via pip install `git+git://github.com/observerss/pygodaddy.git`
 it works :)

Comment: Ah, nice! I didn't know about the pip git instruction so I just copyed the script :) Thank you!